# fgets() reading numbers to space

Tags: c, fgets

I've got a little problem:
I want fgets() to act like scanf("%d",...) - read input to whitespace, not whole line. Is there any way to make it work like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `scanf` does what you want, why not just use `scanf`?

Comment: The thing is, i've got to use fgets, because I've got to check if input is a number and accept only these and scanf doesn't work well here...

Comment: No, fgets() reads until \n or EOF. You'll have to read the line and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fgets()` to save the whole line to a char array. Then write a function that uses `strtok()` to slice your line into substrings, separated by spaces, and check each substring to see if it contains only digits. If it is so, use `sscanf()` to read from that substring to a variable.

Alternatively, you can use `fscanf()` in the first place, with format `"%s"` to read a string from the file. `fscanf()` will stop reading upon reaching a separator (space, new line, etc). Check the string read and if it contains a valid number, use `sscanf()` or `atoi()` to convert it into a numeric value.

I've come up with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VALUE_NOT_PRESENT -1  /* A value you won't expect in your file */

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char s[256];
    int n;

    f = fopen ("test.txt","r");
    fscanf (f, "%s", s);
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        n = VALUE_NOT_PRESENT;
        sscanf (s, "%d", &n); /* if s cannot be converted to a number, n won't
                                 be updated, so we can use that to check if
                                 the number in s is actually a valid number */
        if (n == VALUE_NOT_PRESENT)
            printf ("Discarded ");
        else
            printf ("%d ", n);
        fscanf (f, "%s", s);            
    }
    fclose (f);
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It works by using the ability of `*scanf` family functions to not update the variable if the characters read cannot form a valid number.

Executed with a file with this content:

```
1 2 -3
-4 abc
5 6 a12 6c7
```

It's able to recognize `abc` and `a12` as invalid numbers and so they are discarded. Unfortunately, it recognized `6c7` as the number `6`. I don't know if this is ok for you. If not, you will probably have to write a function that will use a state-machine driven parser to accept or reject the string as a number. I don't know if such function exists in the standard library, but will be surely available out there.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer and time! I'll study these functions abit more and I think I'll manage to finish my code.